# django 1.6 Why can't I display avatars?

Tags: django

First of all, if there is a complete example showing how to upload and display image in a User's ImageField, that would be the best. I can't find it.

1.Ther User model have an edit view `profile_edit`, and it can successfully upload image file to the dictionary `project_name/media/avatar`.

[image]

Related settings.py is:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media').replace('\\','/')+'/'
```

2.Ther User model have an show view `profile`, which shows some fields of the User.

3.Problem is that the `profile` doesnot display the avatar.This is the look.
[image]

this is its html code:
`<td style="background-color:#FFFF99"><img src="avatar/good.png" width="100" height="100" /></td>`

4.After successfully uploading an image file, the `profile_edit` also doesnot display avatar.
[image]

this is its html code:
`<p><label for="id_avatar">头像:</label> 目前: <a href="avatar/good.png">avatar/good.png</a> <input id="avatar-clear_id" name="avatar-clear" type="checkbox" /> <label for="avatar-clear_id">清除</label><br />修改: <input id="id_avatar" name="avatar" type="file" /></p>`

This is the source code, if needed:

```
#settings.py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media').replace('\\','/')+'/'

#ROOT urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'myauth.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls',namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^questions/', include('questions.urls',namespace='questions')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('accounts.views',

    #show the profile
    url(r'^users/(?P<user_pk>\d+)/$',
        'profile',
        {'template_name':'accounts/profile.html'},
        name='profile'),

    #edit the profile
    url(r'^users/(?P<user_pk>\d+)/edit$',
    'profile_edit',
    {'template_name': 'accounts/profile_edit.html'},
    #others ommited...
 )

#views.py ,edit the profile
def profile_edit(request,
    template_name, 
    user_pk,
    edit_form=ProfileForm,
    ):
    request_user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = edit_form(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES,instance=request_user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() 
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                reverse('accounts:profile',kwargs={'user_pk':user_pk}),
                )
    else:
        form = edit_form(instance=request_user)
    context = {
    'form': form,
    }
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,)

#views.py ,show the profile
def profile(request,
    template_name,
    user_pk,
    ):
    profile_user = get_object_or_404(User,pk=user_pk)
    request_user = request.user
    profile_list = [('头像',profile_user.avatar),
    #others ommited...
    ]      
    context={
    'profile_list':profile_list,
    }
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,)

#models.py
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar',null=True,blank=True,verbose_name=_('头像'))  
    #rest fields omitted...

#forms.py
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['avatar','location', 'description', 'signature']

#template.html,edit the profile
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="提交" />
</form>

#template.html,show the profile
<table width="100%">
{% for name,field in profile_list %}
    <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#FFFF99">{{ name }}</td>
    {% if name == "头像" %}
    <td style="background-color:#FFFF99"><img src="{{ field }}" width="100" height="100" /></td>
    {% else %}
    <td style="background-color:#FFFF99">{{ field }}</td>
    {% endif %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Are you testing this locally, with the runserver command ? If so, you need to tell Django it has to serve static files / media, by adding "+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)" to your urlpatterns.

Comment: @Ambroise added, still can't display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form entry given by django is direct url to access that image. If you want to know is your urls are configured properly then click on that link to check the media configuration. If you get 404 error try the @Ambroise's example. To access image in your image tag you need to provide

```
profile_list = [('头像',profile_user.avatar.url)
```

Check this example for your reference

http://lightbird.net/dbe2/forum.html#edit-profile-template

hope it helps :)

Comment: after adding `('头像',profile_user.avatar.url)` ,avatar can be displayed in `profile`, but `profile_edit` still can't.Is it because `form.as_p` requires some settings?

Comment: No By default django doesn't give you image tag while you load form. If you want to display that image you need to show it manually using the image tag. django **ONLY** gives you a link to that image, a clear button if image url exists in database and a file upload input.